# Order by clause doesn't work when Select DISTINCT from #temp table

Tags: sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

Basically, I have a very complicated JOIN statement that I would like to temporary store the result in a #temp table, then I need to reuse this #temp table for multiple other queries. Here are my sample code:

```
INSERT INTO #temp_table
SELECT --some very complicated join statement
FROM --many tables
WHERE --some very complicated conditions
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'LNAME' THEN (Last_Name + First_Name) END,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'FNAME' THEN (First_Name + Last_Name) END
```

`@orderBy will accept either 'LNAME' or 'FNAME' and cannot be NULL.`

Until this part, everything is working fine.

Then, when I perform the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #temp_table
```

There is absolutely no sorting in my result table anymore.

I have tried to do the sorting at the #temp_table, such as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #temp_table
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'LNAME' THEN (Last_Name + First_Name) END,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'FNAME' THEN (First_Name + Last_Name) END
```

But it will give me an error saying that "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Notes:

1. There are `Last_Name` and `First_name` columns in the #temp_table
2. Due to requirement, I cannot combine the `(Last_Name + First_Name)` in the `SELECT` statement. The result MUST show 2 separate columns which are `Last_Name` and `First_Name`
3. PREFERABLY, I want to do the sorting at the `INSERT` statement, because I do not wish to rewrite the `ORDER BY` clause in every of my `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #temp_table` statement.

Comment: You need to select what column(s) you want to be DISTINCT

Comment: select distinct what?, which columns do you want?

Comment: Please look at my edited query above. Thanks for pointing out, I need all of them.

Comment: DISTINCT *? What? Also please read [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by) and [this](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case/). Don't achieve dynamic ordering by concatenating last name and first name. Think about people named Bo Bridge and Bob Ridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to specify the fields you want to select
2. As the error says, the ordered items must appear in the select clause.

That done, the query should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT /*add here any field you want to display*/,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'LNAME' THEN (Last_Name + First_Name) END as Last,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'FNAME' THEN (First_Name + Last_Name) END as First
FROM #temp_table
ORDER BY
Last, First
```

As you write the output into a table, no need to order it before inserting, as the order will be lost, as you noticed.

Comment: Due to requirement, I cannot combine the `(Last_Name + First_Name)` in the `SELECT` statement. The result MUST show 2 separate columns which are `Last_Name` and `First_Name`

Comment: Add them in the select clause as well then. Edited.

Comment: So you mean: Select (Last_Name + First_Name), Last_Name, First_Name.... something like this?

Comment: Now I'm getting `Invalid column name 'last'`. `Invalid column name 'first'` and the original message `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: Did you set a name for the `case when ` columns as shown ? Note that you can also `ORDER BY` the position of the columns in the select clause (i.e. `ORDER BY 1, 2` if the columns to order are in position 1 and 2).

Answer (score 0):

Please read Aaron's comments and links provided but to get it working for your scenario try this:

```
DECLARE @orderBy NVARCHAR(5) = 'FNAME' --order by first name
SELECT
    [first_Name]
  , [Last_name]

FROM
    #temp_table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'LNAME' THEN ( [last_name] + SPACE(1) + [first_Name] )
         WHEN @orderBy = 'FNAME' THEN ( [first_Name] + SPACE(1) + [Last_name] )
    END
```